# Wrong version of ReplicaSets

Tags: kubernetes

I can not understand the behavior of a Deployment. It always uses the wrong version of ReplicaSets in my case. First i did

> kubectl create -f [filename]

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kube-state-metrics
  name: kube-state-metrics
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kube-state-metrics
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kube-state-metrics
```

But а pod could not start because the master node has a taint. I changed the deployment file and added a toleration:

```
spec:
  tolerations:
  - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
    operator: Equal
    effect: NoSchedule
```

> kubectl replace -f [filename]

I got two revisions, but NewReplicaSet was set to old revision and OldReplicaSet to modified version respectively. Hmmm...

I deleted the deployment and called "create" again. The situation did not improve.

```
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   kube-state-metrics-59b7dccd55 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:
Type    Reason             Age   From                   Message
----    ------             ----  ----                   -------
Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  14m   deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set kube-state-metrics-69c88bb67b to 1
Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  14m   deployment-controller  Scaled down replica set kube-state-metrics-69c88bb67b to 0
Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  13m   deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set kube-state-metrics-59b7dccd55 to 1
```

OldReplicaSets is none, but actually is used. And again NewReplicaSets is wrong. In addition, the deployment has two revisions:

```
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         kubectl create --filename=manifests
2         kubectl create --filename=manifests
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean under wrong behavior of the Pod? You can try to check configuration of the Pod using `kubectl get pods <pod_name> -o yaml` and compare it with Deployment yaml file

Comment: OldReplicaSets has value "none" but deployment controller scaled up and down "non existed" replica set and NewReplicaSet point to replica set from my first deployment, which i deleted, not to current. Pod of course use wrong config because it was created by wrong replica set. I should read a source code of kubernetes, it will be the simplest way to find a decision)

Comment: I did not catch what do you mean, could you please describe your steps with more details?